# CSS Text Animated Buttons / Add CSS transition for span content text on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

## Summary

I want to add a Right-Pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark (») to a button text when a user hovers over the botton, using a smooth CSS animation/transition.

## Question

I'd like add a Right-Pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark (») to a button text when the mouse hovers over the button. This works quite well, see my code below. However, when I move the mouse over the button, the text "jumps" instead of moving smoothly, although I've added a transition.

The animated button example on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp looks fine, but doesn't work well buttons with multi line text.

## Code

You can run the code snipplet below.

```css
html {
   font-family: Tahoma;
   margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
}

.svgbutton {
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 2px;
   width: 6em;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #efefef;
   color: black;
   border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
   background-color: transparent;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: 2s;
   vertical-align: top;
}

.svgbutton span {
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   border: thin solid red;
}

.svgbutton span::after {
   content: '';
   opacity: 0;
   border: thin solid blue;
}

.svgbutton:hover span {
}

.svgbutton:hover span::after {
   content: ' \00bb';
   opacity: 1;
   transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<button class="svgbutton" onClick="alert('Click')">
   <svg width="100px" height="60px">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:red;stroke-width:0;"/>
      </svg><br />
   <span>Test</span>
</button>

<button class="svgbutton" onClick="alert('Click')">
   <svg width="100px" height="60px">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:green;stroke-width:0;"/>
   </svg><br />
   <span>Test Test Test</span>
</button>

<button class="svgbutton" onClick="alert('Click')">
   <svg width="100px" height="60px">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke-width:0;"/>
   </svg><br />
   <span>Test Test Test Test</span>
</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The blue and red frame are only inserted for debugging purposes.

How can a make the text move smoothly? Any hint is highly appreciated.

## Final code after the accepted answer

Thanks Paulie_D for your answer: For everyone who is interested, please find my final code here: https://jsfiddle.net/uqgd8bav/

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` cannot be transitioned so I would suggest setting the `width` to zero and transitioning to, say, `1ch` or whatever you feel appropriate.

```css
html {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.svgbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 6em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #efefef;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 2s;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.svgbutton span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid red;
}

.svgbutton span::after {
  content: ' \00bb';
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  //border: thin solid blue;
}

.svgbutton:hover span {}

.svgbutton:hover span::after {
  content: ' \00bb';
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 1ch;
}
```

```html
<button class="svgbutton" onClick="alert('Click')">
   <svg width="100px" height="60px">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:red;stroke-width:0;"/>
      </svg><br />
   <span>Test</span>
</button>

<button class="svgbutton" onClick="alert('Click')">
   <svg width="100px" height="60px">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:green;stroke-width:0;"/>
   </svg><br />
   <span>Test Test Test</span>
</button>

<button class="svgbutton" onClick="alert('Click')">
   <svg width="100px" height="60px">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke-width:0;"/>
   </svg><br />
   <span>Test Test Test Test</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - great answer! I chose to expand the width to 1.7em. However, when I do this, the quotation mark starts to "bounce" left and right for the duration of the animation. Set width to 2em and above to see it clearly. Any idea why this happens or how to fix it (for long animation durations)? (I reduced the animation time to 0.1s, so it can't be seen, but I'd still be curious.)

Comment: Not seeing anything such as you describe in my demo.

Comment: It happens when you expand the width enough, eg. 2ch or more. See https://jsfiddle.net/phxqd351/. Edit: It bounces in Firefox, not in Edge. Strange.